# using mysql, how do I get a table to auto-populate relevant fields from another table based on a foreign key?

Tags: mysql

I have an 'items' table that contains item_id and relevant attributes such as item_length, item_width, item_profile, item_density.

I have a 'project_items' table that contains both attributes and calculated values such as  project_id, item_id, (item_id is a foreign key in the project_items table), project_item_cost_per_boardfoot,  project_item_total_cost, project_square_footage, project_item_weight. The square footage and the cost per board foot are entered on a web form and saved to the database referencing the project they're a part of.

I want the project_items table to be able to auto-populate some of the fields that refer to the particular item based on the item_id and a calculation performed on it.

This is an example item: item_id=1, item_length=10, item_width=5, item_density=2, item_profile=T&G.

For instance, if I select item_id =1, and insert it into project = # 10,  I will have in the project_items table :(using example data)

project_item_id = 1, item_id=1, project_id=10, square_footage = 1000,  project_item_cost_per_boardfoot = $5.00, linear_footage = (virtual stored generated column: ((square_footage*item_width)/12)... which is where I need to pull data from the items table (i.e. item_width) ....board_footage= (linear footage * item_length * item_width)/12, (again, need item_length and item_width from items table) , project_weight = item_density * board_footage (need item_density from items table).

I'm not sure how to do this, and would appreciate any assistance in sorting this out.
I've considered using stored procedures, which I understand how to use though I haven't used them much.  I haven't used triggers but wonder if that would be the way to trigger the autopopulation of the relevant fields in the project_items table based on the item_id.

thanks for any assistance!!!

Initially / to test my calculations, I had put the needed attributes manually in the project_items table,  That introduces redundancy and doesn't solve the problem of needing the fields to auto-populate.  I'm at a loss as to what to try next.

Comment: You do not nees to duplicate your data. Query the details through a join.

Comment: You shouldn't do this, but if you really want to, you can do it with triggers.

Comment: Do the calculations either before inserting or after fetching.  It is rarely advisable to compute one field from other(s).